# VS2015 RTM XUnit Tests: Unable to find the runtime installation directory for the source

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, xunit, dnx

In Visual Studio 2015 RTM, we bumped into an error that no tests are shown in the VS test explorer window. Only getting the following error when rebuild:

```
------ Discover test started ------
Unable to find the runtime installation directory for the source: 'C:\repo\src\Solution\src\Project1.Testing\project.json'
Unable to find the runtime installation directory for the source: 'C:\repo\src\Solution\src\Project2.Testing\project.json'
========== Discover test finished: 0 found (0:00:00.5614723) ==========
```

Project.json looks like:

```
"dependencies": {
    "xunit": "2.1.0-*",
    "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta5"
},
"commands": {
    "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
},
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { } 
}
```

We are using DNX 1.0.0-beta5. Btw, the tests are successfully found and running fine under command line (i.e. by running "dnx . test").

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this problem for a while but your question made me revisit the errors I was getting and found it was because for my main project I had set the runtime specifically to core framework and my test projects were targeting full framework. Tests worked fine from command line. Just now I updated my test projects to target core framework in project properties to make them the same target as my main project and then after build now my tests do appear in test explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do u mean the 'frameworks' section in project.json? Unfortunately both my main project and test project are only using 'dnx451'.

Comment: if they match on target frameworks in the project.json files that is good. also make sure the framework sdk in global.json is the same and also right click each project and click properties to make sure they all are configured to run using the same framework

Comment: Everything is OK in my global.json as well. Fortunately I found out why finally (please see my answer). Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:

Visual Studio menu -> Test -> Test Settings -> Default Processor Architecture -> Set it to X86 solves my problem. (It was set to X64 accidentally).

Btw, (1) if VS could give more information (e.g. the dnx path it looks for), the diagnostic process might be much easier. (2) there is already an architecture property in global.json in my solution, wondering why VS has another global architecture setting that brings a chance of conflict.